# Using Python Generics properly - how can I get the type of the Generic var and enforce the type consistently within an object after initialization?

Tags: python, python-3.x, generics, types, python-3.8

Assume a generic class `Test` that holds a value and a name:

```py
T = TypeVar("T", str, int, float, bool)


class Test(Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self, name: str, value: T):
        self._name: str = name
        self._value: T = value
        self._type: type = T

    def set(self, new: T) -> None:
        self._value = new

    def get(self) -> T:
        return self._value

    def get_type(self) -> type:
        return self._type
```

The above doesn't do what I'd like -- you can `.set` any type as the new value, not only the initial type `T` when the object is created. I also can't figure out how to extract the type `T` -- how to tell if it was a str, int, float, bool without calling `type(test_object.get())`?

```py
bool_var = Test("test", True)
# none of the below works the way I would have hoped:
bool_var.set("str is not a bool")
print("How do I raise an exception on the above line using Generic types?")
# I could store the type and compare it as part of the Test.set function, but is there a way
# to leverage Generics to accomplish this?
print(type(bool_var))
print(bool_var.get_type())
print("where is the value for T at the time the object was created?")
# how do I extract bool from this mess programmatically, to at least see what T was when the object was created?
```

Is what I'm hoping to do just not supported in Python as of yet? Am I approaching Generics the wrong way?

Comment: Type annotations have no runtime effect unless you use a third party tool, for example, a third party static type checker like mypy (which won't have a runtime effect either but you can use to type check your code before running it)

Comment: Third party libs to enforce runtime values include.... pydantic? Marshmallow? Any others? Are there any big philosophical differences / maturity differences between them?

Comment: I would skip the runtime and enforcement altogether and go for a static type checking with `mypy`

Answer (score 0):

types simply have no runtime enforcement, at this moment, they are more a hint to the developer than anything(or used by autodoc tools)

```
x:bool = input("anything as a string:")
```

your ide however may warn you